# Is there a way to know the size of L1, L2, L3 cache and RAM in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems

Is there a way to know the size of the [L1, L2, L3 caches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Multi-level_caches) and RAM in Ubuntu?

Is there a terminal command or files I could look into?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167038/1131

Answer (score 16):

## CPU information

Use  the **lscpu** command:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 6
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               2400.000
BogoMIPS:              6000.33
L1d cache:             16K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

*Listed information is per CPU-core.*

## Memory information

There is the **free** command (-h gives results in human readable form, i.e. GiB rather then bytes):

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.0G       390M       1.6G        10M        15M       160M
-/+ buffers/cache:       215M       1.7G
Swap:         2.0G         0B       2.0G
```

Comment: This is outdated as of [March 19, 2019](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/0e86bc8406959d0d56194d4f404b780e6b70caa4) (lscpu v2.34). The value reported by `lscpu` is now a total. To see per-core info, use `lscpu --cache` and look under the ONE-SIZE header.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you your cache information. Socket Designation will tell you which cache is being referred to in the section.

```
sudo dmidecode -t cache
```

For RAM there are a couple things to look at but meminfo should do it. I used grep here to only show total/free but you could use less or cat to see the whole thing. It shows a lot more information on memory size and usage than just size.

```
grep Mem /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [jkabrams](https://superuser.com/users/281868/jkabrams) answer with following command and filtering "cache" from it, each cache item you have be shown.

```
lscpu | grep cache
```

and RAM:

```
free -h
```

For more information about RAM, processes and so on you can use htop on your distro. Install it like this on ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Answer (score 1):

**sysfs**

```
for d in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index*;
  do tail -c+1 $d/{level,type,size}
  echo
done
```

Gives:

```
==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/level <==
1

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/type <==
Data

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/size <==
32K

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/level <==
1

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/type <==
Instruction

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/size <==
32K

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/level <==
2

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/type <==
Unified

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/size <==
256K

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/level <==
3

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/type <==
Unified

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/size <==
8192K
```

**`getconf`**

```
getconf -a | grep CACHE
```

gives:

```
LEVEL1_ICACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_ICACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_ICACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL1_DCACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_DCACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE                  262144
LEVEL2_CACHE_ASSOC                 8
LEVEL2_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL3_CACHE_SIZE                  20971520
LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC                 20
LEVEL3_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL4_CACHE_SIZE                  0
LEVEL4_CACHE_ASSOC                 0
LEVEL4_CACHE_LINESIZE              0
```

Or for a single level:

```
getconf LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE
```

The cool thing about this interface is that it is just a wrapper around the POSIX `sysconf` C function (cache arguments are non-POSIX extensions), and so it can be used from C code as well:

```
long l2 = sysconf(_SC_LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE);
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

**x86 CPUID instruction**

The CPUID x86 instruction also offers cache information, and can be directly accessed by userland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

glibc seems to use that method for x86. I haven't confirmed by step debugging / instruction tracing, but the source for 2.28 [`sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c;h=b9444ddd52051e05183463340f4dd3cf3e61f4dc;hb=3c03baca37fdcb52c3881e653ca392bba7a99c2b#l281) does that:

```
__cpuid (2, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
```

TODO create a minimal C example, lazy now, asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283171/how-to-receive-l1-l2-l3-cache-size-using-cpuid-instruction-in-x86

ARM also has an architecture-defined mechanism to find cache sizes through registers such as the Cache Size ID Register (CCSIDR), see the [ARMv8 Programmers' Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/den0024/a/DEN0024A_v8_architecture_PG.pdf) 11.6 "Cache discovery" for an overview.